# My update query in MS Access doesn't seem to do anything at all

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

I've made a tool which lets users record information that is relevant to information pulled from a rota which is updated by someone else on an excel spreadsheet.
In Access I've made a link to the data and want to use an update query to update existing information daily due to changes being made on the rota.
Information like Session time, volume of cases and locations.
The code for the query is the following.

```
UPDATE MECOutPut
INNER JOIN [SB Export] 
ON (MECOutPut.[Schedule Date] = [SB Export].[Schedule Date]) 
AND (MECOutPut.PRN = [SB Export].PRN) 
SET MECOutPut.[AM Session] = [SB Export].[Session AM], 
MECOutPut.[AM Volume] = [SB Export].[Volume], 
MECOutPut.[PM Session] = [SB Export].[Session PM], 
MECOutPut.[PM Volume] = [SB Export].[Session PM], 
MECOutPut.MECName = [SB Export].[MEC Name], 
MECOutPut.MECName1 = [SB Export].[MEC Name1]
WHERE (((MECOutPut.[Schedule Date])=[Forms]![frmMain]![txtDate]));
```

This is supposed to update the variable information from the rota export based on the date that is selected in the form. However when running it in datasheet form it pulls the relevant dates but keeps the old data.

Have I done something wrong or do I just need to rebuild?

Thanks

Comment: Your SQL seems to be missing the first line. -- To execute an UPDATE query, you don't open its datasheet, but run it with the red exclamation mark button.

Comment: Apologies Andre, I had marked that out with the code formatting, I have edited it back in

Comment: Did you read the 2nd part of my comment? Because *However when running it in datasheet form* that doesn't run the Update query.

Comment: I will try that out when I log on tomorrow. And yes I read it, I ran the query from the command in VBA. Datasheet was purely to show the results of it.

Comment: @HansUp Sorry for the delay in getting back to you, it returns with 71 rows.
When I run the main Update query now I am getting an error that access was unable to update fields due to a type conversion failure on 67 entries. Will have a look through the data to see if there are any conflicts but the data types match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I feel silly, I worked it out,

The data type was set to number at a glance however one was set to long number the other was set to double.

When I changed them to match the source data it worked instantly.

Thank you and apologies for wasting any time.